# docker container creating in nodes through ansible master

Tags: docker, ansible

I have 2 redhat instances in AWS. One instance is for Ansible master and other is node both have docker in it. Now in ansible master i have a folder named first and in that Dockerfile exists like below where only git is being installed

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04    
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

Now i want to create an image or run a container in the node or locallhost for which iam using command

```
ansible all -s -m shell -a "docker build -t first:latest ."
```

I am getting the below error

```
localhost | FAILED | rc=1 >>
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/test/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

How to proceed with my scenario to have a docker image or docker container in node while executing an ansible ad-hoc command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the files that you have on localhost are not present on every machine. You need to first copy those to some location.

```
ansible all -s -m "synchronize" -a "src=./ dest=/tmp/build/"
```

This will copy your current folder to `/tmp/build` you can also use file module if you are interested in only copying the Dockerfile. Then you should run the build command

```
ansible all -s -m shell -a "docker build -t first:latest /tmp/build"
```

This answer your questions but the approach as such is still not correct as you should be using the `docker_images` module to run the build and not shell

```
ansible all -s -m docker_image -a "name=first tag=latest path=/tmp/build state=build force=yes"
```